# Como criar stages personalizados com Capistrano 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, deploy

Tenho um repositório de onde derivam duas aplicações diferentes. Apesar de compartilharem do mesmo código-fonte, o visual  e banco de dados das duas é diferente, bem como os caminhos no servidor. Bom lembrar que são tratadas como produtos diferentes também.

Sendo assim, eu preciso configurar:

app1_production, app1_staging e app2_production, app2_staging

Na versão 2 do capistrano, eu poderia criar um arquivo pra cada ambiente dentro de config/deploy. Mas na versão 3 parece que isso mudou. Só tem o staging e production. E agora? Tem como eu criar stages customizados como no Capistrano 2?

Answer (score 0):

Bom. Pesquisei melhor e encontrei a solução. Basta fazer isso no momento da instalação:

```
bundle exec cap install STAGES=app1_staging,app1_production,app2_staging,app2_production
```